# Artemis counts and page files

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am trying to fix and old defect from HornetQ that I migrated into my Artemis code.  Do the calls to get queue message count or countMessages take messages in Page files into account. For example if 100 messages are currently in the queue and because of size limits 1000 messages get put into page files does the count tell me the overall count or just what is currently in the active queue. In other words would it tell me 100 or 1100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the message count attribute as well as the `countMessages()` method will count *all* the messages in the queue, including paged messages.

The only exception here is if you pass a filter and/or group-by parameter to `countMessages(String, String)`. That will only count messages in memory.

Comment: I believe this information should make its way to the documentation. :-)